# CGPath intersection(_:using:) and friends (new in iOS 16) broken?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cgpath

There is new functionality in iOS 16 for CGPath (Core Graphics), more precisely there is a function intersection(_:using:) for determining the intersection of two CGPaths (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/3994964-intersection) and several related functions for union, normalization, separating a path into its components etc.

I tested several of them and nothing seems to work. In fact, any randomly composed non-trivial example gives me wrong results. For example, the following code gives me the first picture below: The purple area is the correct intersection.

```
   var pathRedFill = CGMutablePath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10),
                                                  size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 700)),
                                     transform: nil)
           pathRedFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 267, y: 121), control: CGPoint(x: 395, y: 735))
           pathRedFill.closeSubpath()
           
   var pathBlueFill = CGMutablePath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 120),
                                                  size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)), transform: nil)
   pathBlueFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 637, y: 176), control: CGPoint(x: 343, y: 451))
           pathBlueFill.closeSubpath()
           
           context.setBlendMode(.normal)
           
           context.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
           context.addPath(pathRedFill)
           context.drawPath(using: .eoFill)
           
           context.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
           context.addPath(pathBlueFill)
           context.drawPath(using: .eoFill)
```

If I add the following code to calculate the intersection path, I get the second picture. The green line should exactely circle the purple area. But it does not.

```
      context.setLineWidth(4)
      context.setStrokeColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
      let intersectionPath = pathRedFill.intersection(pathBlueFill, using: .evenOdd)
      context.addPath(intersectionPath)
      context.drawPath(using: .stroke)
```

My questions:

1. Is there something that I am doing wrong? (The documentation does not put any requirements on my two paths that I intersect, so my paths are not too complex I should think...)
2. Has anyone experienced similar bugs?

Thank you very much for your help!

[image: Blend of red and blue]

[image: Wrong intersection]

EDIT:
I have done more tests of all the 10 functions added in iOS16 (with correcting the mistake in my path formulation according to DonMag), and tried to find the most simple case where I think something goes wrong. So this (all the other code stays the same, only the paths change)

```
      let pathRedFill = CGPath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300),
                                             size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)),
                                transform: nil)
       
       var pathBlueFill = CGMutablePath()
       pathBlueFill.move(to: CGPoint(x: 302.854156, y: 369.438843))
       pathBlueFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 296.932526, y: 386.031342), control: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 376.0))
       pathBlueFill.closeSubpath()
```

gives the result:

[image]

The green line should circle the purple but does not.

This first was part of an example where there were lots of self-intersections both for the red and for the blue path and I thought the self-intersections of the paths were the problem (since I had some other quite complex examples without self-intersections, but with holes, where everything seemed to go fine). But when I was done stripping to minimum, it turns out that there is something else at odds, as there is no more self-intersections in either path...
When rounding the numbers of the blue path, the error goes away, so it is this kind of degenerate corner case regarding the roots maybe... Also my blue curve is a quadratic (and then there is the line to close the path) whereas it turns out the intersection, stroked in green, is a cubic Bezier.  I am not sure if I am still doing something wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several possibilities...

1. the new path intersection function (and maybe others) are a little "buggy"
2. it's working correctly, but our understanding of how the paths are built is a bit fuzzy
3. a combination of 1 & 2

After some experimentation, I get this with your original code on iOS (not sure why it's flipped vertically -- are you running this on MacOS app?):

[image]

Now, as I understand it, this line:

```
    var pathRedFill = CGMutablePath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10),
                                                 size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 700)),
                                    transform: nil)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
    var pathRedFill = CGMutablePath()
    pathRedFill.move(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))
    pathRedFill.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 410, y: 10))
    pathRedFill.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 410, y: 710))
    pathRedFill.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 710))
    pathRedFill.closeSubpath()
```

The next thing we do is:

```
    pathRedFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 267, y: 121), control: CGPoint(x: 395, y: 735))
    pathRedFill.closeSubpath()
```

And we get our expected output... but, when we complete the rest of the code we're getting (what appears to be) an incorrect intersection.

My guess is that there is some sort of "disconnect" when calling `.addQuadCurve` after the first subpath has been closed.

If we make this change:

```
    var pathRedFill = CGMutablePath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10),
                                                 size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 700)),
                                    transform: nil)
    
    // add this line:
    pathRedFill.move(to: pathRedFill.currentPoint)
    
    pathRedFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 267, y: 121), control: CGPoint(x: 395, y: 735))
    pathRedFill.closeSubpath()
    
    var pathBlueFill = CGMutablePath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 120, y: 120),
                                                  size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)), transform: nil)

    // add this line:
    pathBlueFill.move(to: pathBlueFill.currentPoint)

    pathBlueFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 637, y: 176), control: CGPoint(x: 343, y: 451))
    pathBlueFill.closeSubpath()
```

here's the output:

[image]

So it seems that calling `.moveTo` perhaps *"explicitly starts a new subpath."*

And then, internally, the paths/subpaths are more... complete?

---

**Edit**

For the second part of your question...

I think paths can be much more complex than it would seem on the surface.

For your specific example:

```
let pathRedFill = CGPath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300),
                                      size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)),
                         transform: nil)

var pathBlueFill = CGMutablePath()
pathBlueFill.move(to: CGPoint(x: 302.854156, y: 369.438843))
pathBlueFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 296.932526, y: 386.031342), control: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 376.0))
pathBlueFill.closeSubpath()
```

`pathRedFill` is a **clockwise** path, and `pathBlueFill` is a **counter-clockwise** path.

To see the difference, try changing the `clockwise` var in this code... when set to `true` we get a correct `intersectionPath`:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    else { return }
    
    var pathRedFill = CGMutablePath()
    var pathBlueFill = CGMutablePath()

    // 200 x 300 rect path
    pathRedFill = CGMutablePath(rect: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300),
                                             size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)),
                                transform: nil)

    // switch between true and false to see the difference
    let clockwise: Bool = false
    
    var y1: CGFloat = 369.438843
    var y2: CGFloat = 386.031342
    
    if clockwise {
        let bez = UIBezierPath(cgPath: pathBlueFill)
        if let p = bez.reversing().cgPath.mutableCopy() {
            pathBlueFill = p
        }
    }
    
    pathBlueFill = CGMutablePath()
    
    pathBlueFill.move(to: CGPoint(x: 302.854156, y: y1))
    pathBlueFill.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: 296.932526, y: y2), control: CGPoint(x: 218.5, y: 376.0))
    
    pathBlueFill.closeSubpath()
    
    
    context.setBlendMode(.normal)
    
    context.setFillColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
    context.addPath(pathRedFill)
    context.drawPath(using: .eoFill)
    
    context.setFillColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    context.addPath(pathBlueFill)
    context.drawPath(using: .eoFill)
    
    context.setLineWidth(1)
    context.setStrokeColor(red: 0, green: 1, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
    let intersectionPath = pathRedFill.intersection(pathBlueFill, using: .evenOdd)
    context.addPath(intersectionPath)
    context.drawPath(using: .stroke)

}
```

---

**Edit 2**

The above was meant to demonstrate that mixing clockwise and counter-clockwise subpaths can be problematic. I swapped the `y1` and `y2` values, but didn't take into account the controlPoint y value.

To avoid changing the geometry of the blue path, instead of swapping the `y1` and `y2` values, we can try reversing the path:

```
    pathBlueFill.closeSubpath()

    // reverse the blue path so it's going clockwise
    let bez = UIBezierPath(cgPath: pathBlueFill)
    if let p = bez.reversing().cgPath.mutableCopy() {
        pathBlueFill = p
    }
```

Now we get (I believe) the same geometry, along with the desired intersection path:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much DonMag, my path was indeed wrongly formulated, after the close, I have to start a new subpath and that is what the moveTo does. After this fix, I get your correct image. Btw, everything was upside down because I turned the context upside down, forgot to add that line of code. I have done more tests of all the 10 new functions belonging to that new API and I found the following (I will edit my question with images and code to demonstrate): The API seems still not to work generally on self-intersecting paths, even in a super simple case. Otherwise it works it seems.

Comment: DonMag I will accept your answer after I edited my question (as I am not sure if I can still edit it after an answer has been provided). Thank you again!

Comment: @Céline - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: DonMag, the change of clockwise orientation is indeed achieved by flipping the clockwise bool,  but we also now have geometrically a different fill area for the stand-alone blue. So it is a different path.  The swap of y1 and y2 has  also (if it is really a problem of numerical stability during root finding as I start to loosely conjecture) changed the conditioning of the problem for the better, so for this alternative blue path we get the right results. The orientation for paths for the even odd fill rule is (if I understand right) irrelevant, it only matters for the "(non-zero) winding" rule

Comment: @Céline - see the **Edit 2** in my answer. For this specific example, we **know** the clockwise-or-not direction of each path. For flexible usage, I imagine it would be much more complex -- and may still get "apparently wrong results" with very complex paths (with subpaths, etc).

Comment: DonMag, ok, I misunderstood! Thank you, good, that would work. But, I actually think that your very first answer is the key to the solution of the entire conundrum: I thought again about explicitly having to add the  "move to" as you proposed, and now when I looked at my blue path, although I close (close subpath) the blue path, I do not EXPLICTELY add the line back to the origin myself via pathBlueFill.addLine(to: myStartingPoint), before I call the closeSubpath(). If I add it explicitly, it also gives the right result!!

Comment: Of course that could be a "fix for this example" instead of "THE FIX", but I will both be explicit and keep the "reversing the path idea" in my toolbox. But I think your idea of explicit path construction is probably it! Thank you again for your kind help!